# How does the following Binary Search Tree node removal method work?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

The doubt is concerning the final deletion step (in the **final else** statement) and how the parent nodes reference to child node is reassigned.
The code is from the book *Data structures and Algorithm analysis in C++ by Mark Allen Weiss*.
Reference of entire code: [https://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaa_c++3/code/BinarySearchTree.h](https://users.cis.fiu.edu/%7Eweiss/dsaa_c++3/code/BinarySearchTree.h)

As I understand the program, node pointer **t** points to the node that is to be deleted.
This pointer is then copied to node pointer **oldNode** and then **t** points to a child node if any (in this case a right child due to findMin).
The node pointed by **oldNode** is then deleted.
But how is the parent nodes pointer (**parent->left** or **parent->right** of the parent of node pointed to by **oldNode**) assigned to point to the child node pointed to by **t**?
Is it happening with the conditional assignment of **t**?

Here's the method:

```
 void remove( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode * & t )
    {
        if( t == NULL )
            return;   // Item not found; do nothing
        if( x < t->element )
            remove( x, t->left );
        else if( t->element < x )
            remove( x, t->right );
        else if( t->left != NULL && t->right != NULL ) // Two children
        {
            t->element = findMin( t->right )->element;
            remove( t->element, t->right );
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryNode *oldNode = t;
            t = ( t->left != NULL ) ? t->left : t->right;
            delete oldNode;
        }
    }

//findMin method used in the above routine

BinaryNode * findMin( BinaryNode *t ) const
    {
        if( t == NULL )
            return NULL;
        if( t->left == NULL )
            return t;
        return findMin( t->left );
    }
```

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Because pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `remove` function's signature, `BinaryNode * & t` is a reference to a pointer of type `BinaryNode`. That is, it is a reference *to* the parent's left/right node pointer.

I made a simple diagram for you, since "a picture is worth a thousand words".

So basically, it first saves the actual pointer the reference is referencing (orange arrow) into `oldNode` and then sets the *referenced variable* (red dot) to the pointer pointing to the next child (green arrow), skipping `oldNode` and finally deleting `oldNode`.

[image: Graphical representation]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I can see what's happening.